# SQL in PHP: Checking if number of rows is divisible by a certain number

Tags: php, modulo

I have to do some php work for a student group I am part at in school. Clients make use of our provided services, and every ten requests (which are made online) they make of our service, they are required to do a check-in.

When we receive the request, we get all the info (id, special requests, notes, etc) from our database. I've added the form that indicates if a check-in is required no problem...no issues with the front end. It's just a matter of the backend that I'm unsure of due to my lack of experience in php and mysql.

Here is an example:

```
echo "<td>Half Size</td>";
echo "<td>". ($value["halfsize"] == 1 ? "Yes" : "No") . "<br/>";
echo "</td>";
echo "</tr><tr>";
```

If clients want half size for the request, they fill it out...when we receive it, we see whether that want a full size of half size.

Here is what I want to do with pseudocode, but since I'm lacking in SQL knowledge, I'm not sure what to do.

```
echo "<td>Check-in Required</td>";

**//Check count of rows (any table)
//If divisible by 10 (%10), return "Yes", else "No"**

echo "</td>";
echo "</tr><tr>";
```

What I need to figure out is how to check the number of rows, if that can be divisible by 10 then a check-in is required.

Hopefully that was clear enough and you understand what I'm asking, because reading it back it still sounds a bit hard to follow. I'll be happy to clarify if you have any questions. Thank you!

Comment: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM t1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I completely get what you're doing, but I think what you need is the modulo operator (%).

```
 if(count($rows) % 10 == 0){ // divisible by 10

    }
    else{ //not divisible by 10

    }
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I was looking for...it was more the syntax that I need to brush up on. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

PHP supports modulo which gets the remainder.

```
$divisor = 10;          
$rowCount = 4;          // put your method here that returns the number of rows
$result = $rowCount % $divisor == 0 ? "Yes" : "No";
```

- [PHP Modulo](http://php.net/manual/en/internals2.opcodes.mod.php)

Answer (score 0):

You can alter the database table for clients, add one more column to store the count value.

Add: a column, say, counter --> integer to clients table.

Change your code to do:

1. Every time client makes a request, query select * from clients where id = 
   take out counter value and check if (counter%10 == 0).

   ```
              if(counter%10 == 0)
              {
                request to check in;
              }
                accept request;
                then update clients counter column (increment by 1)
   ```

Updating table will remember requests from previous sessions too. But if you want to check number of requests in only current session, then you just have to add a counter variable in your PHP code and check for %10 before every request.

This was just a pseudo-code. If its tenth request, you request check in, and then accept request and increment clients counter.

else you just accept request and increment counter.

(Sorry for writing just pseudo code, instead of actual code. But that is one way to do it. I may have misunderstood the question, but if this solves your problem, I'm happy.)